# Find when an app was released on the google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I tried searching for a tool online but couldn't find how you can find out when an android app was first released on the google play store?

On google play it just mentions when it was last updated. Any ideas how I can find the first release date ?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, Google doesn't give any helpful results for this query. Thought someone form stackoverflow could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try http://android.stackexchange.com for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: ok thanks i ll post it there